# Unable to run admin privileged CMD.EXE even from User belonging to localgroup "Administrators"

Tags: windows, command-line, permissions, administrator, privileges

Unable to run admin privileged CMD.EXE even from User belonging to localgroup "Administrators".

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open `cmd.exe` as admin.
2. Add user `admin` with password `admin` like so: `net user admin admin /add`.
3. Next add the user to `Administrators` localgroup: `net localgroup Administrators admin /add`.
4. Now the user is added to the `Administrators`. I try to run the `cmd.exe` with this user: `runas /user:admin cmd.exe`. Promts for the password, I enter.
5. The new `cmd.exe` is started, it is, in fact started from the `admin` user.
6. Try to `mkdir C:\Windows\system32\TESTPRIVILEGE`, returns `Access denied`.

What I've tried:

- Removing the user from the `Users` localgroup, leaving them only with `Administrators`.

Why is it not starting as administrator, since the user is clearly a member of `Administrators` localgroup? How can I start a `cmd.exe` with this user **as administrator** without GUI or minimal interaction with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `runas` command starts a CMD instance under the account of `admin`.
However, Windows runs commands as non-elevated, even for administrators.

For starting any command as elevated from the command-line, see the post
[How to open an elevated cmd using command line for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098101/how-to-open-an-elevated-cmd-using-command-line-for-windows)

The highest-voted answer in the post was to use the command:

```
powershell -Command "Start-Process cmd -Verb RunAs"
```